# Simplification of integration of product of Bessel functions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions

I have been trying to evaluate the following integral involving modified Bessel functions:

\begin{align}
\int r I_1 (r) K_1(r) dr
\end{align}

This integral has [an explicit expression given in the Wolfram documentation](https://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselK/21/01/05/01/04/01/0007/) in terms of other Bessel functions. Granted, this expression has divergent components for integer-order Bessel functions but still has a well-defined limit at least for the above case. After performing these manually, one gets that the integral evaluates to

```
1/2 (-1 + r BesselI[0, r] (r BesselK[0, r] + BesselK[1, r]) + 
   r BesselI[1, r] (-BesselK[0, r] + r BesselK[1, r]))
```

However, when evaluating in Mathematica, this returns

```
In[1]:= Integrate[r BesselI[1, r] BesselK[1, r], r]

Out[1]= MeijerG[{{1, 3/2}, {}}, {{1, 2}, {0, 0}}, r, 1/2]/(4 Sqrt[\[Pi]])
```

Furthermore, this Meijer-G function refuses to simplify with FunctionExpand.

Is there a way get Mathematica to simplify the output of the integration? As far as I can see, the Mathematica internals should already know how to perform this simplification (or at least return the indefinite integral not in Meijer-G form).

**Edit:**

Furthermore, if one tries to evaluate

```
Integrate[z BesselI[\[Nu], a z] BesselK[\[Nu], a z], z]
```

as in the docs, Mathematica doesn't actually apply the [rule](https://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselK/21/01/05/01/04/01/0007/) discussed above, instead expressing in terms of hypergeometricPFQ functions. Why isn't this integration rule ever being used?

Comment: Moreover, `Series[MeijerG[{{1, 3/2}, {}}, {{1, 2}, {0, 0}}, r, 1/2]/(
 4 Sqrt[\[Pi]]), {r, 0, 2}]` produces  two "Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered." and $$ \frac{G_{2,4}^{2,2}\left(0,\frac{1}{2}|
\begin{array}{c}
 1,\frac{3}{2} \\
 1,2,0,0 \\
\end{array}
\right)}{4 \sqrt{\pi }}+\text{ComplexInfinity} r+\text{ComplexInfinity} r^2+O\left(r^3\right).$$

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
D[Series[
 Integrate[r BesselI[n,a r] BesselK[n,a r],r] //FunctionExpand, {n,1,0}] 
//Normal//FullSimplify,r]//FullSimplify
(* r BesselI[1, a r] BesselK[1, a r]  *)
```

**Edit:**

By trying different values of n the general case seems to be

```
Integrate[r*BesselI[n,a*r]*BesselK[n,a*r],r]=
-(n/(2*a^2))+(1/2)*r^2*(BesselI[n-1,a*r]*BesselK[n-1,a*r]+
BesselI[n,a*r]*BesselK[n,a*r])+((n*r)/(2*a))*(BesselI[n-1,a*r]*BesselK[n,a*r]-
BesselI[n,a*r]*BesselK[n-1,a*r])
```

Comment: Perhaps you can shed some light on how you obtained the bottom expression? At least, that's not what I get from naive FunctionExpand and FullSimplify routines on the generic form of the integral.

Comment: @Aaron if the limit n-> integer evaluates to indeterminate one can try the series approach as I did above. Then I tried for different n, integer and non integer and checked the derivative symbolically and numerically.

Comment: the term -(n/(2*a^2)) may be omitted as it is just an integration constant